# Can i use "a short time frame" in this sentence "I once submitted a project report with a short time frame literally 1 minute before the deadline."

Tags: meaning, phrases

Can I use "a short time frame" in this sentence to mean "there was not a lot of time for this project report"? Also, can i interchange with "a tight deadline"?

I once submitted a project report with a short time frame literally 1 minute before the deadline.

Comment: Are you talking about the total time you are given, or the remaining time after you were given it a long time ago? And is it an assignment where you have a specific deadline ("Must be submitted by 12 pm on 30 July"), or a case where it is useful to have it done sooner or by a specific time but there is no firm deadline? "Time frame" is often a bit more vague than "deadline": you ask "what sort of time frame do you need that in?" meaning "roughly when do you want it?"

Answer (score 1):

My Answer at least would be:

I once submitted a project report on (a short time frame OR tight deadline), like literally one minute before the deadline.

Ignore the OR and pick either options and it like works either way.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the ELL. Could you provide links for the information you are giving?